# How to check whether the selected tree nodes are of same order?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, user-interface, treeview

[image]

I am designing a treeview which allows the user to select range of nodes by pressing SHIFT, CTRL + start node and then end node.  I requirement is to select the nodes only when the range is under a treenode. (Range should not falls under two parent nodes). If user selects Node2 from two different parents i can check like if(selected_node_1->Parent == selected_node_2->Parent). But if the user selects Node_A and Node_B, how can i check whether the selected treenodes are in same level ?

(Pls note Node_A and Node_B has no parents).

Comment: If one of the nodes doesn't have a parent then they can never match your criteria.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension method (C#):

```
  public static class TreeNodeExtensions {
    public static int Level(this TreeNode value) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); // <- or return 0 

      int result = 0;

      for (TreeNode node = value; node != null; node = node.Parent)
        result += 1;

      return result;
    }
  }

  ... 

  TreeNode node1 = ...
  TreeNode node2 = ...

  if (node1.Level() != node2.Level()) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't they have parent called root? 
if not you can check if both has `parent == null`